# Developing Raspberry Pi Camera apps in OS-X

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, development-environment

I'd like to do some python dev for a camera-based app on a raspberry pi. My ordinary pattern for doing py development is jupyter to test ideas and emacs to write the resulting code all using my apple mac laptop. Typically a deploy any resulting artifacts with jenkins to the production environment.

However, this is my first time using raspberry pi, and the above pattern hasn't been working. Even installing the pycamera library fails in a virtual env.

I wonder, are there patterns for mocking the raspberry pi hardware on osx? How do linux devs work on r.pi?

Answer (score 1):

This may be coming a bit late, but it's possible to install Jupyter on the Pi and develop directly from a browser on your Mac.

If you have a Pi 2 or 3 (or another that includes an ARM7), you can install Miniconda:
https://gist.github.com/simoncos/a7ce35babeaf73f512be24135c0fbafb

If you'd prefer to install Miniconda for Python 2, it is simply referred to as "Miniconda-latest-Linux-arm7l.sh".

There's also a version called Berryconda that appears to support earlier ARM6 flavors of Pi:
https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda

I went the miniconda route for my Pi3, but for the Pi Zero I stuck to the system pythons and a lot of calls to pip and pip3.

Having done it both ways, I think I prefer relying on the system pythons.  Especially for dedicated use of the device (rather that treating it as a general purpose development machine).  Miniconda is stripped down enough, and ARM support is sparse enough, that I find I need to pip a lot of packages even in the miniconda environment.  The only real benefit would be the ability to delete the whole miniconda tree and start clean, but if I'm going to do that I'll probably start the whole OS fresh.

From here you can start to install Jupyter:
http://jupyter.org/install

You can open up the HTTP port for Jupyter on your Pi and access it over your local network, or you can tunnel in over SSH using something like:

```
ssh -L 8001:localhost:8888 raspberrypi.local
```

The way I prefer is to install jupyterhub:
https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub

This is mostly straightforward, the one catch is that you will want to secure the connection with SSL, which probably means a self-signed certificate with something like:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout jupyterhub.key -out
```

The problem is that Safari chokes on self-signed certs.  You'll need to trust it in your keychain:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25443?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

You can temporarily bypass the problem Safari by clicking "visit site", but the long term solution is to click the other option, view the cert, drag it to your desktop, open it in Keychain and then trust it.

You'll want to go through the jupyterhub configuration, but two option that weren't obvious to me, but useful were these:

```
c.JupyterHub.cookie_secret_file = '/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_cookie_secret'
c.JupyterHub.db_url = '/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.sqlite'
```

Set those paths however you'd like, but they'll save you from having files created in whatever directory you start jupyterhub from.

It may also be useful to set jupyterhub to launch at boot:

```
#setup jupyterhub to launch at boot

create /etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service:

[Unit]
Description=Jupyterhub
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
Environment="PATH=/opt/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
ExecStart=/opt/miniconda3/bin/jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


sudo systemctl enable jupyterhub
```

Finally, jupyterlab also works:
http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html
http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jupyterhub.html

Once this is setup, you can develop in Jupyter just as you would on your local machine.  It also gives you access to a terminal from within your browser.

If you dig around, there's also ways to set up your Pi so it shows up in file sharing in Finder and allows you to VNC from the native MacOS screen sharing.

You didn't ask for this specifically, but if you're doing camera work it's worth installing OpenCV.  This should get you most of the way.  It assumes miniconda is installed in `/opt/miniconda3` and includes the flag to build OpenCV for python3:

```
#install opencv
#https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
#note: some optional packages not installed

sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
sudo apt-get install libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev


#from the OpenCV source directory
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.4m \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/opt/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.4m.so \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages \
..


make -j4
#this might take more than one attempt, for some reason it crashed the first time through, but succeeded the second
sudo make install
```